# How could I modify or get the handle of the login form component in Salesforce community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-community

In the builder, I can see some built-in(templated) components.
Do they have a component name so that I could write a custom lightning component and overwrite its behaviour?

Also, is there ant metadata for each community page? So that I could edit them without bothering the builder?
Thanks

[image: inline]

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you looking to override the Login functionality in a Community using custom component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all of the components that you see in the builder are black boxes, if you need a custom lightning component, you will have to code it from scratch unfortunately.

There are some that can be more les interacted with through events which you can find in the aura docs reference.app

https://{custom.lightning.domain}/auradocs/reference.app